# Troubleshooting Lua "qdbus" command via os.execute()

Tags: lua, scripting, archlinux, dbus, qdbus

I'm using ArchLinux/KDE/Plasma and I'm trying to program a lua script (as a plugin in TeamSpeak 3) that will execute the following command, which works in my terminal emulator, but not via a Lua script (that seems to be running as the same user).

The following fails:

```
os.execute("qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Pause")
```

I'm wondering if it's a permissions or library requirement? I know os.execute is working though, because I can run system notifications.  I've tried alternative commands like machinectl, but those fail as well.  I'm very new to Lua, do I need a dbus library?  If so, I have no clue how to implement it.

Comment: Try `os.execute("/bin/sh -c 'your_command'")` instead of `os.execute("your_command")`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I tried that too and it didn't work. :'(

Comment: What values does `os.execute()` return?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to run a custom popen() function and my command returns an empty line.  If I run "whoami", I get the current user logged in, so I know it works.